# JavaScript can't get access to a custom data attribute (console.log returns null)

Tags: javascript, null, console.log, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to (eventually) remove a node/element from the DOM. I made a custom data-attribute, and have to get access to the node/element through there. when console.log the variable I'm trying to gain access to, it returns null. I ran into the same issue when trying to gain access to the header (I'm really new at this), but discovered that I was calling my script tags in the index.html file too early (lol). I don't believe this to be the case, though. We have access to PLAYERS throuhg the index.html file, which is linked to data.js (where PLAYERS is defined). When I run the code in the console, it returns null for console.log(sterling).

Here's my full code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.style.color = "red";
  const playersArray = document.querySelector(".player-container");
  const sterling = document.querySelector('div[data-number="7"]');
  console.log(sterling)

  PLAYERS.forEach(function(player) {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.className = "player"
    div.setAttribute("data-number", player.number)
    div.innerHTML = `
            <h3>${player.name} (<em>${player.nickname}</em>)</h3>
            <img src="${player.photo}" alt=${player.name}>
        `
    playersArray.append(div)
  })

  //sterling.parentNode.removeChild(sterling)
});
```

Comment: You're trying to access the `data-number` attribute before the loop that adds them to the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to query the data attribute before you add it in the `forEach` loop. Move that code to the bottom.

```js
const PLAYERS = [{
    number: 7,
    nickname: "Joe",
    photo: "",
    name: "Joseph"
  },
  {
    number: 2,
    nickname: "Freddy",
    photo: "",
    name: "Frederick"
  }
];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.style.color = "red";
  const playersArray = document.querySelector(".player-container");

  PLAYERS.forEach(function(player) {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.className = "player"
    div.setAttribute("data-number", player.number)
    div.innerHTML = `
            <h3>${player.name} (<em>${player.nickname}</em>)</h3>
            <img src="${player.photo}" alt=${player.name}>
        `
    playersArray.append(div)
  })
  const sterling = document.querySelector('div[data-number="7"]');
  console.log(sterling)

});
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="player-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

But since you're adding the attribute in the same function, you can just set the variable in the loop.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const header = document.getElementById("header");
  header.style.color = "red";
  const playersArray = document.querySelector(".player-container");
  let sterling;

  PLAYERS.forEach(function(player) {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.className = "player"
    div.setAttribute("data-number", player.number)
    div.innerHTML = `
            <h3>${player.name} (<em>${player.nickname}</em>)</h3>
            <img src="${player.photo}" alt=${player.name}>
        `
    playersArray.append(div)
    if (player.number == 7) {
      sterling = div;
    }
  })

  console.log(sterling);
});
```

Comment: so the second solution worked (with the if statement (thank you!!)), but i'm wondering why the first one still returned null? or was that just a stepping stone to the second?

Comment: I added the `PLAYERS` variable and HTML to the first snippet, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It returns null because that element hasn't yet added to DOM. and the function document.querySelector only gets elements existed in DOM.